# Javaを使いSQLServerのストアドから結果一覧を取得したい

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

Javaでシステム開発をしているのですが、SQLServerを使用しデータを取り出したいです。
いま問題となっているのはストアドプロシージャでの結果取得についてです。

私自身前任者から引き継いだばかりのプログラム初心者な上SQLのことはわかりませんので、
本当に申し訳ないですが状況説明すら間違えてる可能性があります。

やりたいことは、
SQLに名簿があり
ストアドプロシージャを実行すると条件にあった人物が表示されるというものです。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

SQLManagementStudio上でストアドプロシージャ実行し、条件にあった検索結果は出て、returnVolumeが0となっています。
上司はSQLは出来るのですがJavaは出来きず、私が未熟なので結果テーブルが取り出せません。

[image: ストアドプロシジャ実行画面]

#### 該当のソースコード

SQL側

```sql
USE [Dcat]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[getExamineeRs]    Script Date: 2018/11/22 15:30:16 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getExamineeRs] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @p_name as nvarchar(50) = null,
    @p_kananame as  nvarchar(50) = null,
    @p_birth as date = null

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here

    declare @return int
    set @return = 0

    select @p_name = ltrim(rtrim(@p_name))

    if (@p_name is null) and (@p_kananame is null) and (@p_birth is null) begin
        --SELECT
        --   [ExamineeId]
        --  ,[ImportGroupId]
        --  ,[ResidentNumber]
        --  ,[ApoDate]
        --  ,[TestDate]
        --  ,[Name]
        --  ,[KanaName]
        --  ,[Gender]
        --  ,[Birth]
        --  ,[Age]
        --  ,[RankId]
        --  ,[LastTestId]
        --  ,[Status]
        --  ,[DeleteFlag]
        --  ,[CreateDate]
        --  ,[CreateUser]
        --  ,[UpdateDate]
        --  ,[UpdateUser]
     -- FROM [dbo].[MExaminee]

        set @return = 200

    end else begin
        if (@p_name is not null) and (@p_kananame is not null) and (@p_birth is not null) begin     
            select
               [ExamineeId]
              ,[ImportGroupId]
              ,[ResidentNumber]
              ,[ApoDate]
              ,[TestDate]
              ,[Name]       = LTRIM(RTRIM([Name]))
              ,[KanaName]   = LTRIM(RTRIM([KanaName]))
              ,[Gender]
              ,[Birth]
              ,[Age]
              ,[RankId]
              ,[LastTestId]
              ,[Status]
              ,[DeleteFlag]
              ,[CreateDate]
              ,[CreateUser]
              ,[UpdateDate]
              ,[UpdateUser]
            FROM [dbo].[MExaminee]
            where
                [Name] = @p_name
            and [KanaName] = @p_kananame
            and [Birth] = @p_birth
        end else begin
            if (@p_name is not null) and (@p_kananame is not null) begin
                select
                   [ExamineeId]
                  ,[ImportGroupId]
                  ,[ResidentNumber]
                  ,[ApoDate]
                  ,[TestDate]
                  ,[Name]       = LTRIM(RTRIM([Name]))
                  ,[KanaName]   = LTRIM(RTRIM([KanaName]))
                  ,[Gender]
                  ,[Birth]
                  ,[Age]
                  ,[RankId]
                  ,[LastTestId]
                  ,[Status]
                  ,[DeleteFlag]
                  ,[CreateDate]
                  ,[CreateUser]
                  ,[UpdateDate]
                  ,[UpdateUser]
                FROM [dbo].[MExaminee]
                where
                    [Name] = @p_name
                and [KanaName] = @p_kananame
                -- and [Birth] = @p_birth
            end else begin
                if (@p_name is not null) and (@p_birth is not null) begin
                    select
                       [ExamineeId]
                      ,[ImportGroupId]
                      ,[ResidentNumber]
                      ,[ApoDate]
                      ,[TestDate]
                      ,[Name]       = LTRIM(RTRIM([Name]))
                      ,[KanaName]   = LTRIM(RTRIM([KanaName]))
                      ,[Gender]
                      ,[Birth]
                      ,[Age]
                      ,[RankId]
                      ,[LastTestId]
                      ,[Status]
                      ,[DeleteFlag]
                      ,[CreateDate]
                      ,[CreateUser]
                      ,[UpdateDate]
                      ,[UpdateUser]
                    FROM [dbo].[MExaminee]
                    where
                        [Name] = @p_name
                    -- and [KanaName] = @p_kananame
                    and [Birth] = @p_birth
                end else begin
                    if (@p_kananame is not null) and (@p_birth is not null) begin
                        select
                           [ExamineeId]
                          ,[ImportGroupId]
                          ,[ResidentNumber]
                          ,[ApoDate]
                          ,[TestDate]
                          ,[Name]       = LTRIM(RTRIM([Name]))
                          ,[KanaName]   = LTRIM(RTRIM([KanaName]))
                          ,[Gender]
                          ,[Birth]
                          ,[Age]
                          ,[RankId]
                          ,[LastTestId]
                          ,[Status]
                          ,[DeleteFlag]
                          ,[CreateDate]
                          ,[CreateUser]
                          ,[UpdateDate]
                          ,[UpdateUser]
                        FROM [dbo].[MExaminee]
                        where
                        --  [Name] = @p_name
                            [KanaName] = @p_kananame
                        and [Birth] = @p_birth
                    end else begin
                        if (@p_name is not null) begin
                            select
                               [ExamineeId]
                              ,[ImportGroupId]
                              ,[ResidentNumber]
                              ,[ApoDate]
                              ,[TestDate]
                              ,[Name]       = LTRIM(RTRIM([Name]))
                              ,[KanaName]   = LTRIM(RTRIM([KanaName]))
                              ,[Gender]
                              ,[Birth]
                              ,[Age]
                              ,[RankId]
                              ,[LastTestId]
                              ,[Status]
                              ,[DeleteFlag]
                              ,[CreateDate]
                              ,[CreateUser]
                              ,[UpdateDate]
                              ,[UpdateUser]
                            FROM [dbo].[MExaminee]
                            where
                                [Name] = @p_name
                            --  [KanaName] = @p_kananame
                            -- and [Birth] = @p_birth
                        end else begin
                            if (@p_kananame is not null) begin
                                select
                                   [ExamineeId]
                                  ,[ImportGroupId]
                                  ,[ResidentNumber]
                                  ,[ApoDate]
                                  ,[TestDate]
                                  ,[Name]       = LTRIM(RTRIM([Name]))
                                  ,[KanaName]   = LTRIM(RTRIM([KanaName]))
                                  ,[Gender]
                                  ,[Birth]
                                  ,[Age]
                                  ,[RankId]
                                  ,[LastTestId]
                                  ,[Status]
                                  ,[DeleteFlag]
                                  ,[CreateDate]
                                  ,[CreateUser]
                                  ,[UpdateDate]
                                  ,[UpdateUser]
                                FROM [dbo].[MExaminee]
                                where
                                --  [Name] = @p_name
                                    [KanaName] = @p_kananame
                                -- and [Birth] = @p_birth
                            end else begin
                                if (@p_birth is not null) begin
                                    select
                                       [ExamineeId]
                                      ,[ImportGroupId]
                                      ,[ResidentNumber]
                                      ,[ApoDate]
                                      ,[TestDate]
                                      ,[Name]       = LTRIM(RTRIM([Name]))
                                      ,[KanaName]   = LTRIM(RTRIM([KanaName]))
                                      ,[Gender]
                                      ,[Birth]
                                      ,[Age]
                                      ,[RankId]
                                      ,[LastTestId]
                                      ,[Status]
                                      ,[DeleteFlag]
                                      ,[CreateDate]
                                      ,[CreateUser]
                                      ,[UpdateDate]
                                      ,[UpdateUser]
                                    FROM [dbo].[MExaminee]
                                    where
                                    --  [Name] = @p_name
                                    --  [KanaName] = @p_kananame
                                        [Birth] = @p_birth
                                end
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end 
    end

    return (@return)
END
```

Java側

```java
        try {
            ResultSet rs = Sql.exec(true, "getExamineeRs", params.name, params.kanaName, params.birth);
            DataTable tbl = new DataTable(rs);

//            DataTable tbl = new DataTable("MExaminee");
            tbl.setLabelMap(
                    "Name", "名前",
                    "KanaName", "フリガナ",
                    "Birth", "生年月日",
                    "Gender", "性別",
                    "ExamineeId", "ID"
            );
            tbl.addHtml(0, "<td><input type=\"button\" value=\"選択\" onclick=\"rowClick(this);\"></td>");
            out.write(tbl.getTable());

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new UserRuntimeException(e);
        }
```

上司は出来るということなので、
色々調べてたのですが、returnVolume以外を取り出す方法がわかりませんでした。

- Java1.8
- SQLServer2017

Comment: おそらく `DataTable` というクラスが、あなたの会社なりプロジェクトなりで独自に作成された物と思われ、その中で行われている(おそらくストアドプロシージャの結果からテーブル的な構造のオブジェクトを作成する)処理に問題があるように見えます。その辺を調べてみてください。また、同じようにsql.exec()も独自のクラスか関数に見えるので、ちゃんと呼び出し・実行・結果取得が行われているかを確かめる必要がありそうです。

Comment: 別サイト [ストアドプロシージャから結果を取得したい](https://teratail.com/questions/159708) で解決したようです。